# What is the length of `Animation` cases (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I haven't found any documentation that indicates what the `TimeInterval` length is for `Animation` cases such as `.easeIn` (`SwiftUI`). I am looking to cover all cases that don't accept `duration` as an argument (aka `.default`, `.linear`, `.easeIn`, `.easeOut`, and `.easeInOut`), does anyone have this information?

Relevant documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation

No luck finding a similar question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think the default values are implementation detail, and are subject to change.

Comment: @Sweeper I appreciate the quick response. Your comment is accepted answer for my question. 



Why I asked in first place: I was looking to create an `async` wrapper for `SwiftUI`'s `withAnimation`. Will be fine without it.

Answer (score 3):

The default TimeInterval for the animations in SwiftUI is 0.35 seconds.

"A method that produces a basic animation with ease-in timing curve, and the given duration. There are variants for the other preset timing curves: .easeOut, .easeInOut and linear. Omitting the duration gives you a default duration of 0.35 seconds. .default is a basic animation with 0.35 seconds duration and an ease-in-ease-out timing curve."

https://www.kodeco.com/books/ios-animations-by-tutorials/v6.0/chapters/1-introduction-to-animations-with-swiftui

Comment: Impressive find. Love Kodeco/Raywenderlich. I am curious if the `0.35` is subject to change, as @Sweeper suggested. I'll wait a bit longer before marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I did some digging and that was all I was able to find in terms of a default TimeInterval. If you find anything else, I'd be interested to know as well!

Comment: While trying to play with standard animations what worked for me is the duration of 0.3s. If I choose the duration of 0.35s for an animation it's out of sync with hiding/showing views from within a stack view